# How to create an object with a custom internal slot?

Tags: javascript, encapsulation, private-members

I recognize that some JavaScript objects have internal slot properties, denoted in the specification by double square brackets **[[ ]]**, which can only be accessed by methods.

For example:

```
var str = new String('example');
```

When inspecting variable `str`, I see that the internal slot **[[PrimitiveValue]]** has the value `'example'`, which I cannot access directly, because it's internal. The only way to access it by the method `toString()`.

How can I implement a custom object with that behavior, with a custom internal property like [[MyField]] and a custom method to access that property?

Comment: Can't you implement your own class and extend `String` that has `[[PrimitiveValue]]`?

Comment: I don't want to extend any available Js object. I'd like to create a new object. For example, I create MyObject with [[MyField]] and the method getMyField to get its value. But don't know does it allow to do this behavior

Comment: I think you can use [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) keyword also.

Comment: @YonggooNoh, thanks for your replies. But that is not my expectation. What I want is to implement exactly the behavior like String class do. I don't know if there is a way to do it.

Comment: You probably want <https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields>.

Answer (score 1):

The `[[PrimitiveValue]]` is an internal property and [you can't interact with it from your code](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/reference/#inspect-internal-properties). But you can emulate the behavior of the `String` class by overriding the `toPrimitive` method:

```js
var str = { 
    [Symbol.toPrimitive]: (hint) =>  {
        return 'example';
    }
};

console.log(`${str}`); // 'example'
```

The `toPrimitive` method is defined in [EcmaScript 6.0, 7.1.1](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-toprimitive). It is called with one parameter called `hint` which can be `'default'`, `'string'` or `'number'`. You can return different values depending on the hint to have an object that behaves like a string and like a number:

```js
var str = { 
    [Symbol.toPrimitive]: (hint) =>  {
        if (hint === 'number') return 111;
        return 'example';
    }
};

console.log(`${str}`); // 'example'
console.log(str * 10); // 1110
```

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can create real [internal properties/slots](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots).

From 262.ecma-international.org:

> The actual semantics of objects, in ECMAScript, are specified via algorithms called internal methods. Each object in an ECMAScript engine is associated with a set of internal methods that defines its runtime behaviour. These internal methods *are not part of the ECMAScript language. They are defined by this specification purely for expository purposes* (emph added KooiInc).

You can however create objects with internal *values* accessible by methods you define - using a [factory function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-are-factory-functions-in-javascript/). For example:

```js
function myNumbersFactory() {
  return function(defaultValue = 0) {
    const internalHistory = [];
    const internalDefaultValue = defaultValue;

    return Object.freeze({
      set value(val) { 
        const nr = parseInt(val);
        internalHistory.push(isNaN(nr) ? internalDefaultValue : nr); },
      get value() { return internalHistory.slice(-1).pop(); },
      get default() { return `default value ${internalDefaultValue}`; },
      get history() { return [...internalHistory]; }
    });
  };
}

const numbers = myNumbersFactory();
const myNumbers = numbers();
const myNumbers2 = numbers(42);

// myNumbers
let i = 0;
myNumbers.value = `will be set to internalDefaultValue (0)`;
while(++i < 6) { myNumbers.value = i; }

myNumbers.value = 42;

console.log(`* myNumbers\n${
  Object.keys(myNumbers)
    .map(k => `${k}: ${myNumbers[k]}`).join(`\n`)}`);
  
// myNumbers2
i = -1;

while(++i < 6) { myNumbers2.value = i; }

myNumbers2.value = `will be set to internalDefaultValue (42)`;

console.log(`* myNumbers2\n${
  Object.keys(myNumbers2)
    .map(k => `${k}: ${myNumbers2[k]}`).join(`\n`)}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: This is functionally identical to <https://stackoverflow.com/a/77095896/3840170>, and has the same flaws.

Answer (score 0):

[From this shim on Github](https://github.com/ljharb/internal-slot):

```
var SLOT = require('internal-slot');
var assert = require('assert');

var o = {};

assert.throws(function () { SLOT.assert(o, 'foo'); });

assert.equal(SLOT.has(o, 'foo'), false);
assert.equal(SLOT.get(o, 'foo'), undefined);

SLOT.set(o, 'foo', 42);

assert.equal(SLOT.has(o, 'foo'), true);
assert.equal(SLOT.get(o, 'foo'), 42);

assert.doesNotThrow(function () { SLOT.assert(o, 'foo'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom object in JavaScript with a private property and a method to access it that mimics the behavior of inner slots. For example:

```
function CustomObject(value) {
  const primitiveValue = value;
  this.getValue = function () {
    return primitiveValue;
  };
}

const obj = new CustomObject('example');
console.log(obj.getValue());
```

Here's the link to the documentation on this topic:

[Private Variables in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#private_variables)

Comment: This is a very dated way to do it; creating a new method per object inside the constructor is wasteful, and it does not replicate the semantics of internal slots perfectly: consider that `new CustomObject('foo').getValue.call(new CustomObject('bar'))` returns `'foo'`, unlike `new String('foo').toString.call(new String('bar'))`.